# Neighborhood Notation

Tags: general-topology, functions, notation

I'm reading the text, "[Elements of General Topology](https://books.google.com/books/about/Elements_of_general_topology.html?id=Msw-AAAAIAAJ)" by Bushaw and he states that his symbol notation for a neighborhood $(N)$ of $x$ on page 13 "isn't customary" (there isn't even Latex for it).  It looks close to something like this:

$x\prec N$

Except there is a line extending from the operator so it forms an arrow.

What is the standard notation for symbolically representing neighborhoods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, no notation is used, you just write “let $N$ be a neighborhood of $x$”. Sometimes, $\mathcal{N}_x$ is used to denote the neighborhood filter at $x$, so one can write $N ∈ \mathcal{N}_x$.

Comment: I have to admit, I was really hoping there was a symbol for the relation.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A neighborhood of an element $x$ of a set $U$ is generally written $N_x$ or sometimes $M_r x$ for the *open-neighborhood of radius $r$* about $x$ in general metric spaces.